# Websphere 7 - universal match pattern ('/**') is defined before other patterns

Tags: spring-security, spring-roo, websphere-7

I have generated a spring project using Roo, and used the security setup addon to add in the spring security. The security works fine on Tomcat 7, but am running into the following problem when trying to deploy to Websphere 7.0.0.19. I'm currently using Spring Security 3.1.0.RELEASE. I've seen other projects use the Spring DelegatingFilterProxy just fine within Websphere. Anybody have any ideas?

Error from StackTrace:

```
E org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored. Please check the ordering in your <security:http> namespace or FilterChainProxy bean configuration
```

applicationContext-security.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd"> 

    <!-- HTTP security configurations -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
        <form-login login-processing-url="/resources/j_spring_security_check" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        <logout logout-url="/resources/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <!-- Configure these elements to secure URIs in your application -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jobtypes/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/tests/**" access="permitAll" />
        <!-- Websphere Problem: IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    </http>

    <!-- Configure Authentication mechanism -->
    <beans:bean name="myCompanyAuthenticationProvider" class="edu.mycompany.project.security.MyCompanyAuthenticationProvider" />
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="myCompanyAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>   
</beans:beans>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For others reading this (and looking for an answer), the issue was logged as [SEC-2034](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2034) and determined to be invalid. The problem is occurring due to the configuration being picked up twice.

Comment: This was due to the contextConfigLocation value being created via Spring Roo, specifically the "web mvc setup" command adds an extra asterisk after classpath.  The issue was logged as [ROO-3241](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3241).

Answer (score 1):

Interesting... I'm using Spring Security 3.1.0.RELEASE and deploying to WAS 7 as well, but I never had issues with any of my apps. The only minor difference between yours and mine is I don't use expressions. Here's how mine looks like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/" authentication-failure-url="/?login_error=1" default-target-url="/"
                             always-use-default-target="true"/>
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    </security:http>

    ...

</beans>
```

Another key difference is my catch-all `/**` is opened for anonymous access whereas yours are restricted to ROLE_USER.

Comment: Appears there was no issue with the actual config, just that the config was being loaded twice.  Thanks for the feedback.